# Alternative to glFramebufferTexture for OpenGL version 3.1 and Oculus Rift

Tags: opengl, oculus

So the Oculus Rift SDK accepts a framebuffer texture ID which is created with the **glFramebufferTexture** function.

Example:

```
    [...]

GLuint l_FBOId;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &l_FBOId);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, l_FBOId);

// The texture we're going to render to...
GLuint l_TextureId;
glGenTextures(1, &l_TextureId);
// "Bind" the newly created texture : all future texture functions will modify this texture...
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, l_TextureId);
// Give an empty image to OpenGL (the last "0")
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, l_TextureSize.w, l_TextureSize.h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
// Linear filtering...
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

// Create Depth Buffer...
GLuint l_DepthBufferId;
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &l_DepthBufferId);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, l_DepthBufferId);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, l_TextureSize.w, l_TextureSize.h);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, l_DepthBufferId);

[...]

/*

Oculus Rift API

*/

ovrGLTexture l_EyeTexture[2];
l_EyeTexture[0].OGL.Header.API = ovrRenderAPI_OpenGL;
l_EyeTexture[0].OGL.Header.TextureSize.w = l_TextureSize.w;
l_EyeTexture[0].OGL.Header.TextureSize.h = l_TextureSize.h;
l_EyeTexture[0].OGL.Header.RenderViewport = l_Eyes[0].RenderViewport;
l_EyeTexture[0].OGL.TexId = l_TextureId;

[...]
```

However, the glFramebufferTexture function is only available in OpenGL 3.2+.

Is it possible to create a workaround that will be functionally equivalent and acceptable to the Oculus Rift SDK?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `glFramebufferTexture2D()`. That function has been available since OpenGL 3.0, when the original framebuffer object (FBO) functionality was introduced.

`glFramebufferTexture()` was added later for more advanced FBO use cases involving cube maps and texture arrays. For simple 2D textures, it's mostly equivalent to `glFramebufferTexture2D()`.

Comment: Thanks. That is what works in the SDK as a replacement!